# Jquery ajax issue in php and ajax code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here in the following code in jquery i get the alert test1 but when i try to get alert test2 i dint got that... there is some issue in code please help me to resolve.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".delete-item-details").click(function() {
    alert('test1');
    var id = $(this).attr('ids');
    alert('test2');
    var order_id = $("#order_id").val();

    goto_url = "/order/DeleteOrderDetailItems/" + id;
    dataString = 'id=' + id + '&order_id=' + order_id;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: goto_url,
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $("#row-id-" + id).fadeOut();
        $("#total_span").html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Open developers console and check errors there.

Comment: Some time console does not show proper errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change this three lines in code and you will definitely get alert !!

```
alert('test1');
                var id=$(this).attr('id');  // here you have written ids
alert('test2');
```

The default attribute  is 'id' not 'ids'

If still now clear let me know i will help you out.

Comment: i was not familiar to use 'id' but i was using 'ids' ... very nice catch by @Moiz Shafat Husain

Answer (score -1):

TRY
var id = $(this).prop('ids');

Comment: you should use this id=$(this).attr('id');